# Angular 2 radio button first always selected even when I need it not to be

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-material

I'm using angular 2 material radio button and a function with attribute [checked] to determine if radio button should be checked or not:

```
<md-radio-group class="th-modal-radio-group">
                    <md-radio-button
                            value="estimated" class="th-modal-radio-btn"
                            [checked]="isChecked('estimated')">Estimated
                    </md-radio-button>
                    <md-radio-button
                            value="contractual" class="th-modal-radio-btn"
                            [checked]="isChecked('contractual')">Contractual
                    </md-radio-button>
                    <md-radio-button
                            value="completed" class="th-modal-radio-btn"
                            [checked]="isChecked('completed')">Completed
                        </md-radio-button>
</md-radio-group>
```

The`isChecked()`function is working correctly but even when it returns `false`on first radio button it appears as default selection. I need that first radio button to be checked ONLY when isChecked returns true

Comment: isChecked('estimated') === true, doesn't work?

Comment: even when I put first [checked]="false" it keeps selecting it as a default option